# Syncfusion data grid how do i get the value of the cell click on by user

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

Using Syncfusion data grid for Xamarin forms how does one get the contents of the value of the cell. I have included the grid events that Syncfusion supply.

https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/datagrid/grid-events

```
<sfgrid:SfDataGrid x:Name="sfGrid" 
        AllowSorting="True"
        ColumnSizer="Star"
        AllowDraggingRow="True"
        SelectedIndex="2"
        AllowResizingColumn="True"
        SelectionMode="Single"
        AllowEditing="True"
        NavigationMode="Cell"
        AllowKeyboardNavigation="True"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Students}">
    <sfgrid:SfDataGrid.Columns x:TypeArguments="syncfusion:Columns">

        <sfgrid:GridTextColumn HeaderText="First Name" 
         MappingName="FirstName" />
        <sfgrid:GridTextColumn HeaderText="Last Name" 
                    MappingName="LastName" />
        <sfgrid:GridTextColumn HeaderText="TB" 
                    MappingName="TB" />
        <sfgrid:GridTextColumn HeaderText="PU" 
                    MappingName="PU" />
    </sfgrid:SfDataGrid.Columns>
</sfgrid:SfDataGrid>
```

Say for example the user taps into the cell for TB and on row 2 that value is 108.7 I want to get that value.

```
 public AcitivtyListPage()
 {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.BindingContext = new StudentsViewModel();        
    sfGrid.CurrentCellActivated += SfGrid_CurrentCellActivated;
    }

  }
```

I tried looking at CurrentCellActivated  but it doesn't appear to have a selected cell value object.

```
 private void SfGrid_CurrentCellActivated(object sender, Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.XForms.CurrentCellActivatedEventArgs e)
 {
        var item = sfGrid.GetSelectedCells();
 }
```

I also treid this example but it doesn't work for the more recent version of the control some methods not longer exist.

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/7436/how-to-get-the-cell-value-of-specific-row-and-column

This graphic should explain its when the red box goes around the grid cell the value I want is contained in that cell see image below.

[image]

Comment: CurrentCellActivatedEventArgs has a CurrentRowColumnIndex property

Comment: Yes but am not wanting the row of data am wanting the cell i taped on @Jason I only want to update its value

Comment: Current**RowColumn**Index - this is the index for a specific cell, not an entire row

Comment: Yes but all it returns me is a number  but not the cell ceotents figure how do i get that  @Jason

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current cell value by using the method GetCellValue() of the SfDataGrid on CurrentCellActivated event. Please refer to the below code snippet.

Code snippet:

```
<syncfusion:SfDataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" SelectionMode="Single" NavigationMode="Cell" CurrentCellActivated="dataGrid_CurrentCellActivated" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding mycollect}" ColumnSizer="Star"> 
  
                <syncfusion:SfDataGrid.Columns> 
                    
                        <syncfusion:GridTextColumn LoadUIView="True" MappingName="No_1"></syncfusion:GridTextColumn> 
                    <syncfusion:GridTextColumn LoadUIView="True" MappingName="No_1"></syncfusion:GridTextColumn> 
                    <syncfusion:GridTextColumn LoadUIView="True" MappingName="No_1"></syncfusion:GridTextColumn> 
                </syncfusion:SfDataGrid.Columns> 
  
            </syncfusion:SfDataGrid>

....
 private void dataGrid_CurrentCellActivated(object sender, CurrentCellActivatedEventArgs e) 
        { 
            
            var dataRow = dataGrid.GetRowGenerator().Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.RowIndex == e.CurrentRowColumnIndex.RowIndex); 
           var CellValue = dataGrid.GetCellValue(dataRow.RowData, dataGrid.Columns[e.CurrentRowColumnIndex.ColumnIndex].MappingName); 
        }
```